# nginx serving files from custom directory residing in home

Tags: nginx, server

In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file I have a server block like this:

```
server {
  location /testme/ {
    root /home/username/sites;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

When I visit `http:localhost/testme/` in my browser, shouldn't files be served from `/home/username/sites/testme/` directory, where I have my simple `index.html`? Instead I get 404 Not Found Error. What I am doing wrong here.

NOTE: I did `sudo nginx -s reload` after changing configuration.

Comment: what does 'http://yoursite/testme' shows?

Comment: what do you mean by yoursite, I am developing locally

Comment: yes, exactly as I specified in my question

Comment: put your single root outside location block & report back.

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: My guess, you didn't remove default nginx's server.

Comment: I did not, but why that interferes?  url matching should go from longest to shortest?